# Using a view as a navigation property in a model

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to map a view to a navigation property in a model ? What I mean by that is:

```
public class First {
    public int FirstId {get;set;}
    public string Field1 {get; set;}
    public string Field2 {get; set;}
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public int AccountId { get; set;}
}

public class VUsefulInformation {
    public int PersonId {get; set;}
    public int AccountId { get; set;}
    public string Color {get;set;}
    public int Length {get;set;}
}
```

`VUsefulInformation` is the view in question and I'd like to add as a nav. property to class `First`, as `First.VUsefulInformation`

I tried using Fluent API to configure the foreign key between the two but the issue is that the view has no knowledge of the `First` table.

```
builder.HasOne<VUsefulInformation>(x => x.VUsefulInformation).WithMany(x => x....?);
```

Is this even logically possible ? EF has enough information to query `VUsefulInformation` using properties on `First`, but does `VUsefulInformation` absolutely need to be able to know about `First` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to configure the `VUsefulInformation` property, EF. spit out an error message saying I should provide a comma separated list of all the values to use as foreign key.

```
[ForeignKey("PersonId,AccountId")]
public virtual VUsefulInformation VUsefulInformation { get; set; }
```

I also have the view entity configured as such

```
public class VUsefulInformationConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<VUsefulInformation>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<VUsefulInformation> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.PersonId, x.AccountId });
    }
}
```

I did not know the attribute could be used as such.